# Unable to update cURL

Tags: php, curl, debian, webmin, virtualmin

I am using Webmin / Virtualmin on a Debian 9 server with PHP 7.3.

My version of cURL is 7.52.1 and since it is obsolete, I would like to update cURL. But I can not...

I installed sudo successfully (the command was not on Debian 9), then I tried:

```
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.67.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf curl-7.67.0.tar.gz
cd curl-7.67.0
./configure
make
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But it's still the old version of cURL that stands out after that.

So I tried:

```
wget https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php-defaults/php-curl_7.3%2B70%2B0~20190814.17%2Bdebian9~1.gbp1e7da2_all.deb
sudo apt install ./php-curl_7.3+70+0~20190814.17+debian9~1.gbp1e7da2_all.deb
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Something seems to have settled, since I can read:
"0 updated, **1 newly installed**, 0 to remove and 45 not updated".

But again, this is the old version that comes out...

I saw that I could also use:

```
sudo gdebi php-curl_7.3+70+0~20190814.17+debian9~1.gbp1e7da2_all.deb
```

But I can not install the gdebi command. When I try one of these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
apt-get install gdebi
sudo apt install gdebi
```

The command prompt crashes after the phrase:

> *After this operation, 152 MB of additional disk space will be used.*

I specify (maybe it's a clue to my problem) that I can not control my version of Curl with one of the following commands:

```
curl -v 
curl --version
```

In this case I get the error message:

> *curl: symbol lookup error: curl: undefined symbol: curl_mime_free*

On the other hand if I upload a php file containing:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(curl_version());
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

I can read there the curl version:

> *["version"]=>   string(6) "7.52.1"*

Thank you very much for your help !

Edit after tests :

@Labradorcode No error with make and make install.

I think back to your idea of ​​problem with multiple instances of curl installed. When I see the logs below, it seems to install in /usr/local/bin/ and not in /usr/bin/ (even if `/usr/bin/curl -V` gives the version and `/usr/local/bin/curl -V` gives an error...)

You can find some examples in strong :

`./configure` result (I truncated the beginning) :

> (...) configure: Configured to build curl/libcurl:
>
> Host setup:       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu   Install prefix:   **/usr/local**
>   Compiler:         gcc    CFLAGS:
>   -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread    CPPFLAGS:            LDFLAGS:             LIBS:
>
> curl version:     7.67.0   SSL:              no
>   (--with-{ssl,gnutls,nss,mbedtls,wolfssl,schannel,secure-transport,mesalink,amissl}
>   )   SSH:              no      (--with-libssh2)   zlib:             no 
>   (--with-zlib)   brotli:           no      (--with-brotli)   GSS-API:
>   no      (--with-gssapi)   TLS-SRP:          no      (--enable-tls-srp)
>   resolver:         POSIX threaded   IPv6:             enabled   Unix
>   sockets:     enabled   IDN:              no
>   (--with-{libidn2,winidn})   Build libcurl:    Shared=yes, Static=yes
>   Built-in manual:  enabled   --libcurl option: enabled
>   (--disable-libcurl-option)   Verbose errors:   enabled
>   (--disable-verbose)   Code coverage:    disabled   SSPI:
>   no      (--enable-sspi)   ca cert bundle:   no   ca cert path:
>   ca fallback:         LDAP:             no      (--enable-ldap /
>   --with-ldap-lib / --with-lber-lib)   LDAPS:            no      (--enable-ldaps)   RTSP:             enabled   RTMP:             no
>   (--with-librtmp)   Metalink:         no      (--with-libmetalink)
>   PSL:              no      (libpsl not found)   Alt-svc:          no
>   (--enable-alt-svc)   HTTP2:            disabled (--with-nghttp2)
>   HTTP3:            disabled (--with-ngtcp2, --with-quiche)   ESNI:
>   no      (--enable-esni)   Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP GOPHER HTTP
>   IMAP POP3 RTSP SMTP TELNET TFTP   Features:         IPv6 UnixSockets
>   AsynchDNS

`make` result :

> Making all in lib make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/lib » make  all-am make[2] : on entre dans le
>   répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/lib » make[2] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/lib » make[1] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/lib » Making all in src make[1] : on entre dans le
>   répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/src » Making all in ../docs make[2] : on
>   entre dans le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/docs » Making all in .
>   make[3] : on entre dans le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/docs » make[3]:
>   rien à faire pour « all-am ». make[3] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs » Making all in cmdline-opts make[3] : on entre
>   dans le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/docs/cmdline-opts » make[3]: rien à
>   faire pour « all ». make[3] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs/cmdline-opts » make[2] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs » make[2] : on entre dans le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/src » make[2]: rien à faire pour « all-am ». make[2] :
>   on quitte le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/src » make[1] : on quitte le
>   répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/src » make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0 » make[1]: rien à faire pour « all-am ». make[1] : on
>   quitte le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0 »

`make install` result :

> Making install in lib make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/lib » make[2] : on entre dans le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/lib »  /bin/mkdir -p '**/usr/local/lib**'  /bin/sh
>   ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libcurl.la
>   '**/usr/local/lib**' libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c
>   .libs/libcurl.so.4.6.0 /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.6.0 libtool:
>   install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libcurl.so.4.6.0
>   libcurl.so.4 || { rm -f libcurl.so.4 && ln -s libcurl.so.4.6.0
>   libcurl.so.4; }; }) libtool: install: (cd **/usr/local/lib** && { ln -s -f
>   libcurl.so.4.6.0 libcurl.so || { rm -f libcurl.so && ln -s
>   libcurl.so.4.6.0 libcurl.so; }; }) libtool: install: /usr/bin/install
>   -c .libs/libcurl.lai /usr/local/lib/libcurl.la libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libcurl.a /usr/local/lib/libcurl.a libtool:
>   install: chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/libcurl.a libtool: install: ranlib
>   /usr/local/lib/libcurl.a libtool: finish:
>   PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/sbin"
>   ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Libraries have been installed in:    **/usr/local/lib**
>
> If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries in a
>   given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and specify the
>   full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR' flag during
>   linking and do at least one of the following:
>      - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
>        during execution
>      - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
>        during linking
>      - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
>      - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'
>
> See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for more
>   information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- make[2]: rien à faire pour « install-data-am ». make[2] : on quitte le
>   répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/lib » make[1] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/lib » Making install in src make[1] : on entre dans le
>   répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/src » Making install in ../docs make[2] : on
>   entre dans le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/docs » Making install in .
>   make[3] : on entre dans le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/docs » make[4] :
>   on entre dans le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/docs » make[4]: rien à
>   faire pour « install-exec-am ».  /bin/mkdir -p
>   '/usr/local/share/man/man1'  /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 curl-config.1
>   /curl-7.67.0/docs/curl.1 '/usr/local/share/man/man1' make[4] : on
>   quitte le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/docs » make[3] : on quitte le
>   répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/docs » Making install in cmdline-opts
>   make[3] : on entre dans le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs/cmdline-opts » make[4] : on entre dans le
>   répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/docs/cmdline-opts » make[4]: rien à faire
>   pour « install-exec-am ». make[4]: rien à faire pour
>   « install-data-am ». make[4] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs/cmdline-opts » make[3] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs/cmdline-opts » make[2] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs » make[2] : on entre dans le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/src » make[3] : on entre dans le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/src »  /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'   /bin/sh
>   ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c curl '/usr/local/bin'
>   libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/curl /usr/local/bin/curl
>   make[3]: rien à faire pour « install-data-am ». make[3] : on quitte le
>   répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/src » make[2] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/src » make[1] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/src » make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0 » make[2] : on entre dans le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0 »  /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'  /usr/bin/install -c
>   curl-config '/usr/local/bin'  /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
>   /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libcurl.pc '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig' make 
>   install-data-hook make[3] : on entre dans le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0 » cd include && make install make[4] : on entre dans le
>   répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/include » Making install in curl make[5] :
>   on entre dans le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/include/curl » make[6] : on
>   entre dans le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/include/curl » make[6]: rien à
>   faire pour « install-exec-am ».  /bin/mkdir -p
>   '/usr/local/include/curl'  /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 curl.h curlver.h
>   easy.h mprintf.h stdcheaders.h multi.h typecheck-gcc.h system.h
>   urlapi.h '/usr/local/include/curl' make[6] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/include/curl » make[5] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/include/curl » make[5] : on entre dans le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/include » make[6] : on entre dans le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/include » make[6]: rien à faire pour
>   « install-exec-am ». make[6]: rien à faire pour « install-data-am ».
>   make[6] : on quitte le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/include » make[5] :
>   on quitte le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/include » make[4] : on quitte
>   le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/include » cd docs && make install
>   make[4] : on entre dans le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/docs » Making
>   install in . make[5] : on entre dans le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs » make[6] : on entre dans le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs » make[6]: rien à faire pour « install-exec-am ». 
>   /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man1'  /usr/bin/install -c -m 644
>   curl-config.1 /curl-7.67.0/docs/curl.1 '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
>   make[6] : on quitte le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/docs » make[5] : on
>   quitte le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/docs » Making install in
>   cmdline-opts make[5] : on entre dans le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs/cmdline-opts » make[6] : on entre dans le
>   répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/docs/cmdline-opts » make[6]: rien à faire
>   pour « install-exec-am ». make[6]: rien à faire pour
>   « install-data-am ». make[6] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs/cmdline-opts » make[5] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs/cmdline-opts » make[4] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs » cd docs/libcurl && make install make[4] : on
>   entre dans le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/docs/libcurl » Making install
>   in opts make[5] : on entre dans le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs/libcurl/opts » make[6] : on entre dans le
>   répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/docs/libcurl/opts » make[6]: rien à faire
>   pour « install-exec-am ».  /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man3' 
>   /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 CURLINFO_ACTIVESOCKET.3
>   CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME.3 CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME_T.3
>   CURLINFO_CERTINFO.3 CURLINFO_CONDITION_UNMET.3 CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME.3
>   CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME_T.3 CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD.3
>   CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD_T.3 CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_UPLOAD.3
>   CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_UPLOAD_T.3 CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE.3
>   CURLINFO_COOKIELIST.3 CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL.3 CURLINFO_FILETIME.3
>   CURLINFO_FILETIME_T.3 CURLINFO_FTP_ENTRY_PATH.3 CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE.3
>   CURLINFO_HTTPAUTH_AVAIL.3 CURLINFO_HTTP_CONNECTCODE.3
>   CURLINFO_HTTP_VERSION.3 CURLINFO_LASTSOCKET.3 CURLINFO_LOCAL_IP.3
>   CURLINFO_LOCAL_PORT.3 CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME.3
>   CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME_T.3 CURLINFO_NUM_CONNECTS.3
>   CURLINFO_OS_ERRNO.3 CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME.3
>   CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME_T.3 CURLINFO_PRIMARY_IP.3
>   CURLINFO_PRIMARY_PORT.3 CURLINFO_PRIVATE.3 CURLINFO_PROTOCOL.3
>   CURLINFO_PROXYAUTH_AVAIL.3 CURLINFO_PROXY_SSL_VERIFYRESULT.3
>   CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT.3 CURLINFO_REDIRECT_TIME.3
>   CURLINFO_REDIRECT_TIME_T.3 CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL.3
>   '/usr/local/share/man/man3'  /usr/bin/install -c -m 644
>   CURLINFO_REQUEST_SIZE.3 CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE.3
>   CURLINFO_RETRY_AFTER.3 CURLINFO_RTSP_CLIENT_CSEQ.3
>   CURLINFO_RTSP_CSEQ_RECV.3 CURLINFO_RTSP_SERVER_CSEQ.3
>   CURLINFO_RTSP_SESSION_ID.3 CURLINFO_SCHEME.3 CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD.3
>   CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD_T.3 CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD.3
>   CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD_T.3 CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD.3
>   CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD_T.3 CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD.3
>   CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD_T.3 CURLINFO_SSL_ENGINES.3
>   CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT.3 CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME.3
>   CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME_T.3 CURLINFO_TLS_SESSION.3
>   CURLINFO_TLS_SSL_PTR.3 CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME.3 CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME_T.3
>   CURLMOPT_CHUNK_LENGTH_PENALTY_SIZE.3
>   CURLMOPT_CONTENT_LENGTH_PENALTY_SIZE.3 CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS.3
>   CURLMOPT_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS.3 CURLMOPT_MAX_HOST_CONNECTIONS.3
>   CURLMOPT_MAX_PIPELINE_LENGTH.3 CURLMOPT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS.3
>   CURLMOPT_PIPELINING.3 CURLMOPT_PIPELINING_SERVER_BL.3
>   CURLMOPT_PIPELINING_SITE_BL.3 CURLMOPT_PUSHDATA.3
>   CURLMOPT_PUSHFUNCTION.3 CURLMOPT_SOCKETDATA.3
>   CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION.3 CURLMOPT_TIMERDATA.3
>   CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION.3 '/usr/local/share/man/man3'  /usr/bin/install
>   -c -m 644 CURLOPT_ABSTRACT_UNIX_SOCKET.3 CURLOPT_ACCEPTTIMEOUT_MS.3 CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.3 CURLOPT_ADDRESS_SCOPE.3 CURLOPT_ALTSVC.3
>   CURLOPT_ALTSVC_CTRL.3 CURLOPT_APPEND.3 CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER.3
>   CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE.3 CURLOPT_CAINFO.3 CURLOPT_CAPATH.3
>   CURLOPT_CERTINFO.3 CURLOPT_CHUNK_BGN_FUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_CHUNK_DATA.3
>   CURLOPT_CHUNK_END_FUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETDATA.3
>   CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT.3
>   CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS.3 CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY.3
>   CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO.3 CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_NETWORK_FUNCTION.3
>   CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_UTF8_FUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_CONV_TO_NETWORK_FUNCTION.3
>   CURLOPT_COOKIE.3 CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE.3 CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR.3
>   CURLOPT_COOKIELIST.3 CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION.3 CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS.3
>   CURLOPT_CRLF.3 CURLOPT_CRLFILE.3 CURLOPT_CURLU.3
>   CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST.3 CURLOPT_DEBUGDATA.3 CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION.3
>   CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL.3 CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY.3
>   CURLOPT_DISALLOW_USERNAME_IN_URL.3 CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT.3
>   '/usr/local/share/man/man3'  /usr/bin/install -c -m 644
>   CURLOPT_DNS_INTERFACE.3 CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4.3
>   CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP6.3 CURLOPT_DNS_SERVERS.3
>   CURLOPT_DNS_SHUFFLE_ADDRESSES.3 CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE.3
>   CURLOPT_DOH_URL.3 CURLOPT_EGDSOCKET.3 CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER.3
>   CURLOPT_EXPECT_100_TIMEOUT_MS.3 CURLOPT_FAILONERROR.3
>   CURLOPT_FILETIME.3 CURLOPT_FNMATCH_DATA.3 CURLOPT_FNMATCH_FUNCTION.3
>   CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.3 CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE.3
>   CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT.3 CURLOPT_FTPPORT.3 CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH.3
>   CURLOPT_FTP_ACCOUNT.3 CURLOPT_FTP_ALTERNATIVE_TO_USER.3
>   CURLOPT_FTP_CREATE_MISSING_DIRS.3 CURLOPT_FTP_FILEMETHOD.3
>   CURLOPT_FTP_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT.3 CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP.3
>   CURLOPT_FTP_SSL_CCC.3 CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPRT.3 CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPSV.3
>   CURLOPT_FTP_USE_PRET.3 CURLOPT_GSSAPI_DELEGATION.3
>   CURLOPT_HAPPY_EYEBALLS_TIMEOUT_MS.3 CURLOPT_HAPROXYPROTOCOL.3
>   CURLOPT_HEADER.3 CURLOPT_HEADERDATA.3 CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION.3
>   CURLOPT_HEADEROPT.3 CURLOPT_HTTP09_ALLOWED.3 CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES.3
>   CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH.3 CURLOPT_HTTPGET.3 '/usr/local/share/man/man3' 
>   /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.3 CURLOPT_HTTPPOST.3
>   CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL.3 CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING.3
>   CURLOPT_HTTP_TRANSFER_DECODING.3 CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION.3
>   CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH.3 CURLOPT_INFILESIZE.3
>   CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE.3 CURLOPT_INTERFACE.3
>   CURLOPT_INTERLEAVEDATA.3 CURLOPT_INTERLEAVEFUNCTION.3
>   CURLOPT_IOCTLDATA.3 CURLOPT_IOCTLFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE.3
>   CURLOPT_ISSUERCERT.3 CURLOPT_KEEP_SENDING_ON_ERROR.3
>   CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD.3 CURLOPT_KRBLEVEL.3 CURLOPT_LOCALPORT.3
>   CURLOPT_LOCALPORTRANGE.3 CURLOPT_LOGIN_OPTIONS.3
>   CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT.3 CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME.3 CURLOPT_MAIL_AUTH.3
>   CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM.3 CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT.3 CURLOPT_MAXAGE_CONN.3
>   CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS.3 CURLOPT_MAXFILESIZE.3
>   CURLOPT_MAXFILESIZE_LARGE.3 CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS.3
>   CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE.3 CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE.3
>   CURLOPT_MIMEPOST.3 CURLOPT_NETRC.3 CURLOPT_NETRC_FILE.3
>   CURLOPT_NEW_DIRECTORY_PERMS.3 CURLOPT_NEW_FILE_PERMS.3
>   CURLOPT_NOBODY.3 '/usr/local/share/man/man3'  /usr/bin/install -c -m
>   644 CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS.3 CURLOPT_NOPROXY.3 CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL.3
>   CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETDATA.3 CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION.3
>   CURLOPT_PASSWORD.3 CURLOPT_PATH_AS_IS.3 CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY.3
>   CURLOPT_PIPEWAIT.3 CURLOPT_PORT.3 CURLOPT_POST.3 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.3
>   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE.3 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE.3
>   CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE.3 CURLOPT_POSTREDIR.3 CURLOPT_PREQUOTE.3
>   CURLOPT_PRE_PROXY.3 CURLOPT_PRIVATE.3 CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA.3
>   CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS.3 CURLOPT_PROXY.3
>   CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH.3 CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER.3 CURLOPT_PROXYPASSWORD.3
>   CURLOPT_PROXYPORT.3 CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE.3 CURLOPT_PROXYUSERNAME.3
>   CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_CAINFO.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_CAPATH.3
>   CURLOPT_PROXY_CRLFILE.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_KEYPASSWD.3
>   CURLOPT_PROXY_PINNEDPUBLICKEY.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_SERVICE_NAME.3
>   CURLOPT_PROXY_SSLCERT.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_SSLCERTTYPE.3
>   CURLOPT_PROXY_SSLKEY.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_SSLKEYTYPE.3
>   '/usr/local/share/man/man3'  /usr/bin/install -c -m 644
>   CURLOPT_PROXY_SSLVERSION.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_CIPHER_LIST.3
>   CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_OPTIONS.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_VERIFYHOST.3
>   CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_VERIFYPEER.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_TLS13_CIPHERS.3
>   CURLOPT_PROXY_TLSAUTH_PASSWORD.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_TLSAUTH_TYPE.3
>   CURLOPT_PROXY_TLSAUTH_USERNAME.3 CURLOPT_PROXY_TRANSFER_MODE.3
>   CURLOPT_PUT.3 CURLOPT_QUOTE.3 CURLOPT_RANDOM_FILE.3 CURLOPT_RANGE.3
>   CURLOPT_READDATA.3 CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS.3
>   CURLOPT_REFERER.3 CURLOPT_REQUEST_TARGET.3 CURLOPT_RESOLVE.3
>   CURLOPT_RESOLVER_START_DATA.3 CURLOPT_RESOLVER_START_FUNCTION.3
>   CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM.3 CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM_LARGE.3
>   CURLOPT_RTSP_CLIENT_CSEQ.3 CURLOPT_RTSP_REQUEST.3
>   CURLOPT_RTSP_SERVER_CSEQ.3 CURLOPT_RTSP_SESSION_ID.3
>   CURLOPT_RTSP_STREAM_URI.3 CURLOPT_RTSP_TRANSPORT.3
>   CURLOPT_SASL_AUTHZID.3 CURLOPT_SASL_IR.3 CURLOPT_SEEKDATA.3
>   CURLOPT_SEEKFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_SERVICE_NAME.3 CURLOPT_SHARE.3
>   CURLOPT_SOCKOPTDATA.3 CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_SOCKS5_AUTH.3
>   CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_NEC.3 '/usr/local/share/man/man3' 
>   /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_SERVICE.3
>   CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES.3 CURLOPT_SSH_COMPRESSION.3
>   CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_MD5.3 CURLOPT_SSH_KEYDATA.3
>   CURLOPT_SSH_KEYFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_SSH_KNOWNHOSTS.3
>   CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE.3 CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE.3
>   CURLOPT_SSLCERT.3 CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE.3 CURLOPT_SSLENGINE.3
>   CURLOPT_SSLENGINE_DEFAULT.3 CURLOPT_SSLKEY.3 CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE.3
>   CURLOPT_SSLVERSION.3 CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST.3 CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_DATA.3
>   CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN.3
>   CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_NPN.3 CURLOPT_SSL_FALSESTART.3
>   CURLOPT_SSL_OPTIONS.3 CURLOPT_SSL_SESSIONID_CACHE.3
>   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST.3 CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.3
>   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS.3 CURLOPT_STDERR.3 CURLOPT_STREAM_DEPENDS.3
>   CURLOPT_STREAM_DEPENDS_E.3 CURLOPT_STREAM_WEIGHT.3
>   CURLOPT_SUPPRESS_CONNECT_HEADERS.3 CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN.3
>   CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE.3 CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE.3 CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPINTVL.3
>   CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY.3 CURLOPT_TELNETOPTIONS.3 CURLOPT_TFTP_BLKSIZE.3
>   CURLOPT_TFTP_NO_OPTIONS.3 '/usr/local/share/man/man3' 
>   /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 CURLOPT_TIMECONDITION.3 CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.3
>   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS.3 CURLOPT_TIMEVALUE.3 CURLOPT_TIMEVALUE_LARGE.3
>   CURLOPT_TLS13_CIPHERS.3 CURLOPT_TLSAUTH_PASSWORD.3
>   CURLOPT_TLSAUTH_TYPE.3 CURLOPT_TLSAUTH_USERNAME.3
>   CURLOPT_TRAILERDATA.3 CURLOPT_TRAILERFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT.3
>   CURLOPT_TRANSFER_ENCODING.3 CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH.3
>   CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH.3 CURLOPT_UPKEEP_INTERVAL_MS.3
>   CURLOPT_UPLOAD.3 CURLOPT_UPLOAD_BUFFERSIZE.3 CURLOPT_URL.3
>   CURLOPT_USERAGENT.3 CURLOPT_USERNAME.3 CURLOPT_USERPWD.3
>   CURLOPT_USE_SSL.3 CURLOPT_VERBOSE.3 CURLOPT_WILDCARDMATCH.3
>   CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.3 CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_XFERINFODATA.3
>   CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION.3 CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER.3
>   '/usr/local/share/man/man3' make[6] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs/libcurl/opts » make[5] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs/libcurl/opts » make[5] : on entre dans le
>   répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/docs/libcurl » make[6] : on entre dans le
>   répertoire « /curl-7.67.0/docs/libcurl » make[6]: rien à faire pour
>   « install-exec-am ».  /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/aclocal' 
>   /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libcurl.m4 '/usr/local/share/aclocal' 
>   /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man3'  /usr/bin/install -c -m 644
>   curl_easy_cleanup.3 curl_easy_duphandle.3 curl_easy_escape.3
>   curl_easy_getinfo.3 curl_easy_init.3 curl_easy_pause.3
>   curl_easy_perform.3 curl_easy_recv.3 curl_easy_reset.3
>   curl_easy_send.3 curl_easy_setopt.3 curl_easy_strerror.3
>   curl_easy_unescape.3 curl_easy_upkeep.3 curl_escape.3 curl_formadd.3
>   curl_formfree.3 curl_formget.3 curl_free.3 curl_getdate.3
>   curl_getenv.3 curl_global_cleanup.3 curl_global_init.3
>   curl_global_init_mem.3 curl_global_sslset.3 curl_mime_addpart.3
>   curl_mime_data.3 curl_mime_data_cb.3 curl_mime_encoder.3
>   curl_mime_filedata.3 curl_mime_filename.3 curl_mime_free.3
>   curl_mime_headers.3 curl_mime_init.3 curl_mime_name.3
>   curl_mime_subparts.3 curl_mime_type.3 curl_mprintf.3
>   curl_multi_add_handle.3 curl_multi_assign.3
>   '/usr/local/share/man/man3'  /usr/bin/install -c -m 644
>   curl_multi_cleanup.3 curl_multi_fdset.3 curl_multi_info_read.3
>   curl_multi_init.3 curl_multi_perform.3 curl_multi_poll.3
>   curl_multi_remove_handle.3 curl_multi_setopt.3 curl_multi_socket.3
>   curl_multi_socket_action.3 curl_multi_socket_all.3
>   curl_multi_strerror.3 curl_multi_timeout.3 curl_multi_wait.3
>   curl_share_cleanup.3 curl_share_init.3 curl_share_setopt.3
>   curl_share_strerror.3 curl_slist_append.3 curl_slist_free_all.3
>   curl_strequal.3 curl_strnequal.3 curl_unescape.3 curl_url.3
>   curl_url_cleanup.3 curl_url_dup.3 curl_url_get.3 curl_url_set.3
>   curl_version.3 curl_version_info.3 libcurl-easy.3 libcurl-env.3
>   libcurl-errors.3 libcurl-multi.3 libcurl-security.3 libcurl-share.3
>   libcurl-symbols.3 libcurl-thread.3 libcurl-tutorial.3 libcurl-url.3
>   '/usr/local/share/man/man3'  /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libcurl.3
>   '/usr/local/share/man/man3' make[6] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs/libcurl » make[5] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs/libcurl » make[4] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0/docs/libcurl » make[3] : on quitte le répertoire
>   « /curl-7.67.0 » make[2] : on quitte le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0 »
>   make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /curl-7.67.0 »

Sorry for failed line breaks.

Comment: show us output from command "whereis curl", looks like you have got two different versions of cURL in different locations.

Comment: ooh ok, I see issue, you have to "make install" after make command, and should be ok.

Comment: Thank you @Labradorcode. I try "make install" after "make" but I still see the old cURL after that. And here is the output of "whereis curl": `/usr/bin/curl /usr/local/bin/curl /usr/share/man/man1/curl.1.gz` . Maybe I must use the Webmin panel to do this update ? But I don't know how to do.

Comment: ok. let's check version for both binaries, first /usr/bin/curl -V and next /usr/local/bin/curl -V, as you see you have to CURL in different locations.

Comment: @Labradorcode `/usr/bin/curl -V` shows "curl 7.52.1" and `/usr/local/bin/curl -V` show this error "symbol lookup error: /usr/local/bin/curl: undefined symbol: curl_mime_free"

Comment: ref to this https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/1646, try to upgrade libcurl

Comment: Thank you @Labradorcode. But when I try `apt install libcurl --reinstall` or `apt-get upgrade libcurl`, I have the error "E: Can not find libcurl package"

Comment: try apt-get update, apt-get --only-upgrade install libcurl4

Comment: @Labradorcode It gives " E: Can not find libcurl4 package"

Comment: try lower version such as libcurl3

Comment: @Labradorcode It gives "libcurl3 is already the newest version (7.52.1-5+deb9u9)"

Comment: that must be something with your compilation of 7.67, no errors with make and make install?

Comment: @Labradorcode No error with make and make install.

I think back to your idea of ​​problem with multiple instances of curl installed. When I see the logs below, it seems to install in /usr/local/bin/ and not in /usr/bin/ (even if `/usr/bin/curl -V` gives the version and `/usr/local/bin/curl -V` gives an error...)

You can find some examples in strong in the logs I add in my question above.

Comment: reboot please...

Comment: @PauloBoaventura Thank you for your comment. I already tried to reboot, nothing changed...

Comment: @triphop Hello i would like to know if you managed to install it because as incredible as it seems i needed the famous gdebi

Answer (score 0):

Hello Thanks for responding and I'm sorry for being so brief in my last reply.

Why use gdebi if you could use dpkg

---

### 1 situation

**Using DPKG**

```
dpkg -i [name] .deb
```

---

### 2 situation

Did you try to uninstall completely?

```
apt remove --purge curl
```

**and / or**

```
apt remove --purge curl *
```

***Note when uninstalling dependencies.
If any essential VirtualMin modules are being uninstalled with this command. .
In this case, something other than CURL and part of it. Do not continue. When he asks if you accept or not to uninstall packages.***

***In this case...
Take advantage of the list generated in the terminal to collect the vital names for the uninstallation, manual.
The [*] in the command is only in extreme cases. And it should be used only with the certainty that it does not compromise the installation of Virtualmin.
In my opinion, it is your case. But try without it, okay.***

The cleanup is to remove all dependencies and settings attached to the main repository [curl].
It may be these dependencies / settings that are causing conflict.

---

### 3 situation

***Case study: - THE EXTREME***

Well, in my case, particularly, I would do the following situations.

If you are on a VPS. Make a backup of your data and don't forget the most important ones. Mainly databases.
Preferably, leave this disk on hold if you need to access it via Snaphost.

After that, create a new VPS machine and install CURL before anything else. If the system reports an error immediately ...
You already know that this can be Debian.
Try testing another Linux operating system like Ubuntu. There are generally fewer errors.
In the case of Debian, it has several complexities in certain installations, which makes the process boring and very tiring. Which could be quite simple, as I see that it is your case.

An alternative is to use a Google Console account to test.

I do not recommend using Centos 7, because in the medium term it usually gives annoying bugs.